# subiquity partition manager, lvm

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, lvm, 20.04, subiquity

I'm learning the new ubuntu 20.04 server live installer.

In the `d-i` installer it was possible to implement relatively complex partitioning: which involved mdadm + lvm in different combinations.

But in this case I'm stuck at a simplest config.

I allocated the whole disk for an LVM PV (it does not allow create a PV on a GPT partition).

Created a VG for the whole PV, then a LV for the whole VG.

Mounted it as an ext4 at `/`.

Yet as you can see on a screenshot - the `Done` button is unavailable. `Use as a boot device` is unavailable either.

What am I doing wrong?

Or how can I trigger this partitioner to re-read the schema (so that I could at least partition everything manually).

**UPD**: I believe it's a bug hence I reported it https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity/+bug/1876273

[image]

Comment: it might be worth to also post that here: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/please-test-autoinstalls-for-20-04/15250  The creator of this is using that ;-)

Comment: It's for autoinstalls though?